# Fake Daylight Saving transition

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

Is there a way to configure Daylight Saving transition time in Joda-Time?

For example, the spring transition in California will begin at 2:00 am on 3/11.

I'd like to configure Joda-Time (my app is using) so that the transition begins at a specific time (e.g 4pm on 2/21), so that I can test some logics in my app depending on the Daylight Saving per current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone`:

```java
public class FakeTimeZone extends DateTimeZone {

    private DateTime dstStart;

    private DateTimeZone zone;

    protected FakeTimeZone(String id) {
        super(id);
        this.zone = DateTimeZone.forID(id);
        // DST starts at 21/Feb/2018, at 4 PM 
        this.dstStart = new DateTime(2018, 2, 21, 16, 0, 0, 0, zone);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNameKey(long instant) {
        return this.getID();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOffset(long instant) {
        // check if it's in DST
        if (dstStart.getMillis() <= instant) {
            // DST, offset is 1 hour ahead the standard - value must be in milliseconds
            return this.zone.getStandardOffset(instant) + 3600000;
        }
        return this.zone.getStandardOffset(instant);
    }

    @Override
    public int getStandardOffset(long instant) {
        return this.zone.getStandardOffset(instant);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFixed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public long nextTransition(long instant) {
        if (instant < dstStart.getMillis()) {
            return dstStart.getMillis();
        }
        return instant;
    }

    @Override
    public long previousTransition(long instant) {
        if (instant > dstStart.getMillis()) {
            return dstStart.getMillis();
        }
        return instant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof FakeTimeZone) {
            return getID().equals(((FakeTimeZone) obj).getID());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It uses the same offsets of the timezone you pass in the constructor, the only difference is the DST transitions - in this case, I'm using just one and ignoring the rest - but you can change the code above and make a more complex logic to consider all the other transitions + your custom transition.

Then you just use it like this:

```java
// 1 hour before DST starts
DateTime d = new DateTime(2018, 2, 21, 15, 0, 0, 0, new FakeTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));

// This prints 2018-02-21T15:00:00.000-08:00 (standard offset)
System.out.println(d);

// 1 hour later, DST is in effect, it prints 2018-02-21T17:00:00.000-07:00
System.out.println(d.plusHours(1));
```

Note that the first date is 3PM (one hour before DST starts), so the offset is the standard (**-08:00**).

Then, and 1 hour later, it was supposed to be 4PM, but due to DST start, it's shifted to 5PM and the offset changes to **-07:00**.